# Filter rows lesser than the cumulative maximum

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter rows based on a relative simple criteria. If the value for `Open` is less than the `max` value for the column until that row, it gets dropped, otherwise the row stays and is the reference value for the new `max`. 
This is the starting example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'Date':['22-01-2019','23-01-2019','24-01-2019','25-01-2019','26-01-2019'],'Open': [40,54,54,79,67], 'Close': [43,53,65,65,61]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

In this case I would like to do the filtering on the column `Open`:

```
         Date  Open  Close
0  22-01-2019    40     43 #Max is 40
1  23-01-2019    54     53 #54 is higher than 40 so it stays
2  24-01-2019    54     65 #This is not higher than the previous max, should get dropped
3  25-01-2019    79     80 #This is higher than 54, so it stays
4  26-01-2019    67     61 #This is not higher than 79, should get dropped
```

The only way I could come up to solve the problem with a `for` loop iterating over each row in particular, defining an auxiliary variable that records does comparison, and returns a boolean series. However it's extremely inefficient when dealing with more than 100k rows. The final goal is to perform the same filter on the `Close` column and join them to know in which days (the original data is every 15 minutes) both Open and Close values have risen above the highest value ever (previously) recorded.

Finally the output should look like this:

```
         Date  Open  Close
0  22-01-2019    40     43
1  23-01-2019    54     53
3  25-01-2019    79     80
```

If doing the same operation for the `Close` column it should look like:

```
         Date  Open  Close
0  22-01-2019    40     43
1  23-01-2019    54     53
2  24-01-2019    54     65
3  25-01-2019    79     80
```

The final goal (which I would know how to do once the I can get through the filtering part, but just sharing for the sake of the full case) is:

```
         Date  Open  Close
0  22-01-2019    40     43
1  23-01-2019    54     53
3  25-01-2019    79     80
```

My solution is:

```
max_v = 0
list_for_filtering = []
for i, value in df.iterrows():
        if value['Open'] > max_v:
            max_v = value['Open']
            list_for_filtering.append(True)
        else:
            pass
            list_for_filtering.append(False)
df['T/F'] = list_for_filtering
```

And filter keeping only the `True` values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution is to compare "Open" with the shifted cummax:

```
# thanks to Andy L. for the simplification!
df[df['Open'] > df['Open'].cummax().shift(fill_value=-np.inf)]

         Date  Open  Close
0  22-01-2019    40     43
1  23-01-2019    54     53
3  25-01-2019    79     65
```

Where,

```
df['Open'].cummax().shift()

0     NaN
1    40.0
2    54.0
3    54.0
4    79.0
Name: Open, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Good call, I forgot about `cummax`. Had `cumcount` and `cumsum` in mind but couldn't get them to work anyhow. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain some more how this works?  You simplified this comparison very well and I'd like to understand it better so I can generalize it.  Thanks!!

Comment: NIce one :) +1. I think use `fill_value=-np.inf` or `fillna(-np.inf)` will surely make first row always `True`

Comment: @AndyL. very nice, thanks! Forgot the `fill_value` argument of `shift`.

Comment: @merit_2 Sure, which part exactly? The idea here is to compare every row with the max of all rows above it.

Comment: I've been playing with it and I think I understand. For example, I did df[df['Open']!= df['Open'].shift().fillna(-1)] to remove rows in df that were duplicates that are right next to each other.  Your method doesn't seem to be a list comprehension but similar? Your method says df rows are now replaced where > df['Open'].cummax().shift(fill_value=-np.inf)